# How can I split bash CLI arguments into two separate arrays for later usage?

Tags: arrays, bash

New to StackOverflow and new to bash scripting. I have a shell script that is attempting to do the following:

1. cd into a directory on a remote machine. Assume I have already established a successful SSH connection.
2. Save the email addresses from the command line input (these could range from 1 to X number of email addresses entered) into an array called 'emails'
3. Save the brand IDs (integers) from the command line input (these could range from 1 to X number of brand IDs entered) into an array called 'brands'
4. Use nested for loops to iterate over the 'emails' and 'brands' arrays and add each email address to each brand via add.py

I am running into trouble splitting up and saving data into each array, because I do not know where the command line indices of the emails will stop, and where the indices of the brands will begin.  Is there any way I can accomplish this?

command line input I expect to look as follows:

```
me@some-remote-machine:~$ bash script.sh person1@gmail.com person2@gmail.com person3@gmail.com ... personX@gmail.com brand1 brand2 brand3 ... brandX
```

The contents of script.sh look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd some/directory
emails= ???
brands= ???
for i in $emails
do
for a in $brands
    do
    python test.py add --email=$i --brand_id=$a --grant=manage
done
done
```

Thank you in advance, and please let me know if I can clarify or provide more information.

Answer (score 3):

Use a sentinel argument that cannot possibly be a valid e-mail address. For example:

```
$ bash script.sh person1@gmail.com person2@gmail.com '***' brand1 brand2 brand3
```

Then in a loop, you can read arguments until you reach the non-email; everything after that is a brand.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd some/directory
while [[ $1 != '***' ]]; do
  emails+=("$1")
  shift
done
shift   # Ignore the sentinal
brands=( "$@" )    # What's left

for i in "${emails[@]}"
do
  for a in "${brands[@]}"
    do
    python test.py add --email="$i" --brand_id="$a" --grant=manage
  done
done
```

If you can't modify the arguments that will be passed to `script.sh`, then perhaps you can distinguish between an address and a brand by the presence or absence of a `@`:

```
while [[ $1 = *@* ]]; do
    emails+=("$1")
    shift
done
brands=("$@")
```

I'm assuming that the number of addresses and brands are independent. Otherwise, you can simply look at the total number of arguments `$#`. Say there are N of each. Then

```
emails=( "${@:1:$#/2}" )  # First half
brands=( "${@:$#/2+1}" )  # Second half
```